# Labels on navigationbar in swift

Tags: ios, swift, controller, navigation

**I have three views in navigationBar.**

I want to place labels on navigation bar so that when i will go to one view to another it will show the page number . Here is my code. I have written this code in The viewDidLoad of all the three class

```
     if let navigationBar = self.navigationController?.navigationBar {

        let firstFrame = CGRect(x: navigationBar.frame.width/2, y: 8, width: 15, height: 10)

        let secondFrame = CGRect(x: navigationBar.frame.width/2 + 30, y: 8, width: 15, height: 10)

        let thirdFrame = CGRect(x: navigationBar.frame.width/2 + 60, y: 8, width: 15, height: 10)

        let firstLabel = UILabel(frame: firstFrame)
        firstLabel.text = "1"

        let secondLabel = UILabel(frame: secondFrame)
        secondLabel.text = "of"
        let thirdLabel = UILabel(frame: thirdFrame)
        secondLabel.text = "3"

        navigationBar.addSubview(firstLabel)
        navigationBar.addSubview(secondLabel)
        navigationBar.addSubview(thirdLabel)
    }
```

But the problem is the same label repeating in every view controller.It is showing like "1 of 3" in every view controller *

Comment: What are you using? `UIPageViewController`?

Comment: No , ViewController with Navigation controller

Comment: And you just go from first ViewController to second and from second to third?

Comment: yes . first to second and second to third

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create subclass of UINavigationController

```
class NavigationController: UINavigationController {
}
```

don't forget to change class of your `UINavigationController` in Storyboard

[image]

now in your `UINavigationController` subclass create properties of your labels and set them

```
class NavigationController: UINavigationController {

    var firstLabel: UILabel?
    var secondLabel: UILabel?
    var thirdLabel: UILabel?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        firstLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: navigationBar.frame.width/2, y: 8, width: 15, height: 10))
        secondLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: navigationBar.frame.width/2 + 30, y: 8, width: 15, height: 10))
        thirdLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: navigationBar.frame.width/2 + 60, y: 8, width: 15, height: 10))
        navigationBar.addSubview(firstLabel)
        navigationBar.addSubview(secondLabel)
        navigationBar.addSubview(thirdLabel)
        firstLabel.text = "1"
        secondLabel.text = "of"
        thirdLabel.text = "3"
    }
}
```

then you want to change `firstLabel.text` every time you move to another ViewController. So, in ViewController in `viewWillAppear` get reference for your `NavigationController` and set text of this `firstLabel` like this

```
class ViewController1: UIViewController {
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        if let navController = navigationController as? NavigationController {
            navController.firstLabel?.text = "1"
        }
    }
}
```

and then do the same for second and third `UIViewController`

```
class ViewController2: UIViewController {
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        if let navController = navigationController as? NavigationController {
            navController.firstLabel?.text = "2"
        }
    }
}

...
```

Comment: Hi Robert, I have done as you suggest. but why the label is not showing. Am i doing any thing wrong ?

Comment: @Tapan I'am sorry, I have just updated my answer. In NavigationController subclass in viewDidLoad I forgot to add subviews to navigationBar